# Why do relativisitic partial derivatives commute?

Tags: general-relativity, derivatives

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{\mu\nu} &=& \partial_\mu (A_\nu(x)) - \partial_\nu (A_\mu(x))
\\
&\rightarrow& \partial_\mu (A_\nu(x)+ \partial_\nu(\alpha(x))) - \partial_\nu (A_\mu(x)+ \partial_\mu(\alpha(x)))
\\
&=& \partial_\mu (A_\nu(x))+ \partial_\mu\partial_\nu(\alpha(x)) - \partial_\nu (A_\mu(x)) - \partial_\nu\partial_\mu(\alpha(x))
\\
&=& \partial_\mu (A_\nu(x)) - \partial_\nu (A_\mu(x)) 
\\
&=& F_{\mu\nu}
\end{eqnarray*}

Why is $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu(\alpha) = \partial_\nu\partial_\mu(\alpha)$?

Why is the mixed partials rule from high school math,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f$$

true?

Comment: Please check your calculations before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are symmetric, the last term in third line shoud be $−\partial_\nu\partial_\mu\alpha$, you forgot the minus sign

Comment: and why are they symmetric? edited. thank you

Comment: @LopeyTall They are symmetry because you are considering your $\alpha(x)$ as a $C^2$ function, as usual in Physics. Gauge fields are continuous, so assuming $C^2$ you are automatically impossing continuity

Answer (score 3):

Remember that 
$$\partial_\mu = {\partial \over \partial x^\mu}$$
and that $x$ corresponds to $x^1$, $y$ to $x^2$, so there is no difference here (apart from notation) from high school maths.

As for why it is true, this is Clairaut's theorem, or [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz's_theorem). It holds provided that second partial derivatives are continuous, and it is a minor pain to prove. I confess, I do think the proof I give in my third book is simpler and more elegant, but it still seems like too much effort to transcribe it into mathjax as the theorem is so natural that it is more surprising that there are functions (without continuous second partial derivatives) for which it does not hold.

Comment: For functions with discontinuous derivatives the theorem still holds. The problem arises if the *partial* derivatives fail to be continuous (and the function isn't differentiable).

Comment: @JannikPitt, that is not the theorem I quoted. If the partial derivatives are not continuous (do not exist), you cannot even make the statement. In this case there is no problem even to be stated.

Comment: A function can be differentiable with discontinuous partial derivatives, and partially differentiable but not differentiable. Only continuous differentiability and continuous partial differentiability are equivalent.

Comment: Ok, I see I accidentally missed a word. I have inserted it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a theorem in elementary analysis, often called Clairut's theorem or the Schwarz theorem:

> Let  $U \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be open and $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ be twice differentiable. Then
>   $$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} =  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}.$$

A proof can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives?oldformat=true). Its essential component is applying the mean value inequality to a suitable choosen function. 
Note that the theorem is wrong if the function is only partially differentiable twice where the partial derivatives are not continuous. A counterexample can be found on the Wikipedia page as well. 
Note that if the function is twice differentiable and the derivatives are discontinuos it remains true.

In physics most of the time we assume that all involved functions are smooth unless stated otherwise, so no problem arises.